# How to make a io.systemfileswatcher run indefinitely

Tags: powershell

I have a script that calls two io.systemfile watchers which I would like to run 24x7 so that it can detect data that needs to be processed and automatically hand it off to a script that processes it (and uploads the result to the network):

```
Function Report1Watcher{

param ($folder)


$filter = "*vac*.csv"

$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    InternalBufferSize = 65536
}

Write-Host "Watching $folder for creation of $filter files..."

$changeAction = {

        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated


       $Actionpath = Split-Path $Path


        write-host $Actionpath " Ready for Report1"



       Report1 $Actionpath

       write-host $Actionpath " Report1 Generated"


 }

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName "Created" -Action $changeAction



}




Function Report2Watcher{

param ($folder)


$filter = "*4.4*"


$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    InternalBufferSize = 65536
}

Write-Host "Watching $folder for creation of $filter files..."






$changeAction = {

        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated




      $Actionpath = Split-Path $Path

      $Actionpath = Split-Path $Actionpath


      write-host $Actionpath " Ready for Report2"



      Report2 $Actionpath


      write-host "Report2 Generated" 




 }

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName "Created" -Action $changeAction




}



Function Watchmaster{



Report1Watcher $Testdir

Report2Watcher $Testdir 



}

Watchmaster
```

I am thinking of turning it into a windows service, but would it be able to run 24x7 as is? I'm not sure where I could add an infinite loop without creating infinite io.systemfilewatchers. I know as a PS script that powershell would need to constantly be running. But if I created a batch file that runs this and set it up as a service with nssm would this accomplish what I need?

Comment: Schedule the script in task scheduler with an interval of 1 min or 2 mins.. That should get your work done. Also you can create it as a service.

Comment: But will this cause it to create new watchers every 1-2 minutes, or only check that the initial watchers are still active every 1-2 minutes and then restart them if not

Comment: Do not create watcher in the script. Just schedule the script to to run on every interval and whenever it will run , you just `test-path` the file is present or not...So you don't need to have any watcher specifically inside the script apart from the basic `test-path` validation

Comment: I believe I do need a watcher because there are several files that would activate a test path on the target directory, I need to disregard them and only focus on ones when they are added.

Comment: Be VERY careful using NSSM and confirm that it is from a reputable source. I installed this on a customer site and it came with a ransomware virus that took them down. I had to rebuild their machine from scratch which cost me money and time. I would recommend using Apache Tomcat Service instead.

Comment: @Brice I installed it through chocolatey, I should be good right?